# Prove that for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, $\boldsymbol{n} \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have come up with a proof myself. I am not sure if it is a well-written proof from the view of a mathematician.

We shall first show that $\boldsymbol{n} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that $\boldsymbol{0} = \emptyset$. It is immediately clear that $\boldsymbol{0} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Next assume that $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\boldsymbol{n} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. According to definition, $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} = \boldsymbol{n} \cup \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}$. From the induction hypothesis, $\boldsymbol{n} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Also, as $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, $\left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Then $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. As a result, $\boldsymbol{n} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ implies $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. So we may conclude that $\boldsymbol{n} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Next, assume that $\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n}$. We shall show that $\boldsymbol{n} \not\in \boldsymbol{m}$. Assume $\boldsymbol{n} \in \boldsymbol{m}$. Then $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n} < \boldsymbol{m}$, as $\in$ is the same as $<$ for $\mathbb{N}$. As $<$ is transistive, we have $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{m}$, and this indicates $\boldsymbol{m} \in \boldsymbol{m}$, which contradicts the fact that $\boldsymbol{s} \not\in \boldsymbol{s}$ for all $\boldsymbol{s} \in \mathbb{N}$. As a result, we have $\boldsymbol{n} \not \in \boldsymbol{m}$ for any $\boldsymbol{n} > \boldsymbol{m}$. This indicates that $\boldsymbol{n} \neq \mathbb{N}$ for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, $\boldsymbol{n} \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$.

---

I find this conclusion useful in many proofs for a set being infinite. For instance, to show $X$ is infinite if $\mathbb{N} \preceq X$. This is why I prove it myself. Proof for the proposition: $X$ is infinite if $\mathbb{N} \preceq X$, is also provided.

Suppose that $\mathbb{N} \preceq X$ and $X$ is finite. Then $X \approx \boldsymbol{n}$ for some $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. So there exists a bijection $f: X \to \boldsymbol{n}$. Also, as $\mathbb{N} \preceq X$, there is a one-one function $g: \mathbb{N} \to X$. The composite function $f \circ g: \mathbb{N} \to \boldsymbol{n}$ is a one-one function. Then the restriction of $f\circ g$ to $\boldsymbol{n}$, $\left(f\circ g\right)\vert_{\boldsymbol{n}}: \boldsymbol{n} \to \boldsymbol{n}$ is also one-one (the proved lemma ensures the existence of this restriction). The pigeon-hole theorem tells us that $\left(f\circ g\right)\vert_{\boldsymbol{n}}$ is also onto. Consider $\boldsymbol{m} \in \mathbb{N}$ while $\boldsymbol{m} \not\in \boldsymbol{n}$ (the proved lemma implies that this $\boldsymbol{m}$ exists). According to the definition of $f \circ g$, $\left(f\circ g\right)\left(\boldsymbol{m}\right) \in \boldsymbol{n}$. As $\left(f\circ g\right)\vert_{\boldsymbol{n}}: \boldsymbol{n} \to \boldsymbol{n}$ is onto, there has to exist $\boldsymbol{p} \in \boldsymbol{n}$ such that $\left(f\circ g\right)\vert_{\boldsymbol{n}}\left(\boldsymbol{p}\right) = \left(f\circ g\right)\left(\boldsymbol{m}\right)$. As $\left(f\circ g\right)\vert_{\boldsymbol{n}}\left(\boldsymbol{p}\right) = \left(f\circ g\right)\left(\boldsymbol{p}\right)$, we can see that $f\circ g\left(\boldsymbol{m}\right) = f\circ g\left(\boldsymbol{n}\right)$, where $\boldsymbol{m} \neq \boldsymbol{p}$. This conclusion contradicts that $f \circ g$ is one-one. Thus, $X$ is infinite.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the intersection of all inductive subsets of an inductive set.